How to Parallelize Responses to Multiple User Queries in Langchain
I am currently developing a chatbot using Langchain, and I load the model using LlamaCPP. The responses are generated through a chain process. However, I encounter an issue where the process crashes immediately if a new prompt is input while the model is generating a response.
What I am looking to achieve is the ability for the model, once loaded, to handle multiple inputs in parallel. The model is stored as a gguf file, and it utilizes approximately 12GB of GPU memory.
Additionally, when using the vllm library with the same gguf file, it consumes about 73GB of memory(H100 in use). Could someone help me understand the cause of this high memory usage?
Thank you!
I have tried several methods like apredict, abatch, arun from the chain, but all attempts have failed.
If you need any additional information, I'll be happy to provide it.

My assumption is that the GPU instance of the H100 can't be split and can only run one process at a time, so every time you use it, it takes all the available memory even if it doesn't need it. Can you use more and smaller instances? I think that and implementing some load balancing shoud do it.

Thank you. Is this something that can't be solved with features like Handler or callback manager inside Langchain? I'm also considering VLLM.
